# Passing ajax variable in Fancybox 2

Tags: php, html, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am working with Fancybox 2. And I am working in a page that has a gallery and on clicking a image it should pass a ajax value to the server and in return I want to bring in some information back.

The idea is simple :- There will be number of images fetched from the database with a "id" and then this id should be sent to the server and rest server sends back the result as a popup box.

I saw the demo and I have no idea of ajax here. I just want to know how will I pass value to the server if this is the code :-

```
<a href=" ? "><img src="image.jpg"></a>
```

Any idea how do I pass value using `<a href=" ? ">`

Please let me know how do I pass data to the server using the above code ?

Comment: share your demo page link...

Comment: could be good if you also provide the code you are using to pass variables to your server (without fancybox) and what is the format of the response you get

Comment: I don't know much about ajax and stuff. I just got some tuts from the web and have this

            <?php
    if($num_alumni > 0){
     while($res_alumni = mysql_fetch_array($query_alumni)){
   
   ?>
            <a href="upload/alumni/<?=$res_alumni['img'];?>" title="<?=$res_alumni['content'];?>">
            <img src="<?=$thumb_url;?>?x=100&y=90&src=upload/alumni/<?=$res_alumni['img'];?>&f=0" alt="<?php echo $res_alumni['name'];?>" title="<?php echo $res_alumni['name'];?>" vspace="0" border="0" /> </a>  
            <?php } } ?>

now I don't know how do I pass values to the server from this